# R converting nested for loops_the nested parallel foreach doesn't work

Tags: r, foreach, nested-loops, doparallel, stringdist

I have a table with ~1M entry points (where each line is an insurance contract, i.e. one client can have multiple contracts) and cols `client_id`, `names` and `adresses`.
The problem I am trying to solve is that the same client can have  different `client_id` for each new contract.

To resolve this I have done the following:

1. Creating a `New_ID` as a 4th col in the table
2. Iterate twice over `names`and calculate names similarity for each combination
3. Iterate twice over `adresses`and calculate names similarity for each combination
4. Inside each iteration: if `name_similarity` > 0.9 & `adresses_similarity` > 0.8 then `New_ID` takes the value of j

## Used packages + fake data:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(stringdist) # strings' similarities 
library(parallel)   # parallel programming 
library(foreach)    # parallel programming 
library(doParallel) # parallel programming 
library(doSNOW)     # parallel programming 

# Fake data 
client_id <- 1:6
names <- c("Name", "Naaame", "Name", "Namee", "Nammee", "Nammee")
adresses <- c("Adress", "Adressss", "Adress", "Adresss", "Aadressss", "Aadressss")

A <- data.frame(cbind(client_id, names, adresses)) %>% 
  mutate(New_ID = NA)
```

## Script

The below nested for loops works well:

```
for(i in seq_along(A$client_id)){
  for(j in seq_along(A$client_id)){
    
        # calculate names similarities 
        name_similarity <- stringdist::stringsim(A$names[i],
                                                 A$names[j],
                                                 method = "osa",
                                                 useBytes = T)
        
        # calculate adresses similarities
        adresses_similarity <- stringdist::stringsim(A$adresses[i],
                                                 A$adresses[j],
                                                 method = "qgram",
                                                 useBytes = T)
        
        # Decision & New_ID attribution 
        if(name_similarity > 0.9) {
          if(adresses_similarity > 0.85){
            A[i , 4] = j # New ID
          }
        } # decision end 
        
  } # Close j loop 
} # Close i loop
```

Although the script above produces the expected result, it will take days to iterate over the real data size (~ 1M). So I thought of parallel programming.

## Parallel programming:

I have tried to nest two foreach using the operator `%:%` and run it in parallel using the operator `%dopar%` of the `doParallel` package.

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())         # Intiate clusters (I have 8 cores on my local machine) 
registerDoSNOW(cl)                       # relate foreach to a parallel mecanism from {parallel} 
clusterExport(cl, list("A"))             # export data to clusters  
clusterEvalQ(cl, c(library(tidyverse), 
                   library(stringdist))) # export used packages to child clusters 

foreach(i = seq_along(A$client_id) ) %:% 
  foreach(j = seq_along(A$client_id)) %dopar%{
    
        # calculate names similarities 
        name_similarity <- stringdist::stringsim(A$names[i],
                                                 A$names[j],
                                                 method = "osa",
                                                 useBytes = T) 
        
        # calculate adresses similarities
        adresses_similarity <- stringdist::stringsim(A$adresses[i],
                                                 A$adresses[j],
                                                 method = "osa",
                                                 useBytes = T)
        
        # Decision & New_ID attribution 
        if(name_similarity > 0.9) {
          if(adresses_similarity > 0.85){
            A[i , 4] = j # New ID
          }
        } # decision end 
  }
  
stopCluster(cl)
```

However, after running the parallel nested `foreach` loops, the `New_ID` column still empty.
I've tried to `unlist()` the result as the `foreach` loop returns values in list, it doesn't work.

How can I write the nested parallel `foreach` to obtain the same result as in the nested `for` loops? Thanks